# Having trouble deleting the root node and resorting in a max heap

Tags: python, list, function, data-structures, heap

I am writing a function that is supposed to remove the root node from a maxheap which is represented by a list. I'm having trouble reordering to satisfy the maxheap property after I remove the root node. Here is my code:

```
def deleteMax(x):
    x.pop(0)
    curr = self.heap[0]
    rootindex = 0
    leftchild = rootindex*2+1
    rightchild = rootindex*2+2

    while current < x[leftchild] or current < x[rightchild] :
        if current < leftchild :
            x[rootindex ], x[leftchild] = x[leftchild], x[rootindex ]
            rootindex = leftchild
        else:
            x[rootindex ], x[rightchild] = x[rightchild], x[rootindex ]
            rootindex = rightchild

    return x
```

### Example

x = []

**Insert is my insert function that inserts the values in the correct order. Just assume I'm inserting properly**

**insert(10)**

**insert(5)**

**insert(14)**

**insert(9)**

**insert(2)**

**insert(11)**

**insert(6)**

So: x = [14, 9, 11, 5, 2, 10, 6] (which is correct)

But when I call deleteMax(), it removes 14 perfectly fine but I'm left with:

[9, 11, 5, 2, 10, 6]

When I want it to be this to satisfy the maxheap property and make it this:

[11, 9, 10, 5, 2, 6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm for removing the root of a max-heap is:

```
Move the last node in the heap to the root position.
Reduce the heap count by 1.
Set current to the root node.
while current is smaller than either of its children
    swap current with the largest child
    set current to index of the child you swapped it with
```

### Update

Your updated code is almost right, but it doesn't guarantee that you select the largest child. For example if you have this:

```
        1
      5   7
```

You would swap 1 with 5. You need to make sure you get the largest of the children. So:

```
current = 0
while (true)
    leftchild = current*2+1
    rightchild = current*2+2
    largest = current

    if (current >= size)
        break;
    if (x[current] < x[leftchild])
        largest = leftchild
    if (rightchild < size && x[largest] < x[rightchild])
        largest = rightchild
    if (largest == current)
        break
    swap(x[current], x[largest])
    current = largest
```

The code above ensures that you always select the largest of the two children, and also ensures that you don't inadvertently test for a right child that isn't there.

Comment: @CodeGolferPro Seem my update. In my previous post, I said "smallest", when I meant "largest". I was thinking of min-heap. Also, I provided the correct algorithm for ensuring that you get the correct child for swapping.

Comment: @CodeGolferPro That's a C-like pseudo code. The idiom `while (true)` is a convenient way of saying, "do this forever". It's like saying 'while (1 == 1)`. The result of that comparison is always true. Of course it doesn't actually go forever: the `break` statements break out of the loop as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm isn't quite right. Take at look at the animation on this page: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/heap_data_structure.htm

What you're doing now is to start with the last element and then move it up. Instead, you need to take that last element, put it at the top (where the element you just popped used to be), then move it down.

If we just remove the first element of the array, then the heap breaks because the rows are all misaligned and the parent/child links are shifted, so you need to put something back in that spot.